# Is there an easy way to see the earliest version of pandas that a particular function appeared in?

Tags: python, pandas, documentation

I recently ran into an issue with calling `sns.scatterplot` where the seaborn version loaded into the backend of the platform I was using was too old. I discovered through a post here on stackoverflow that the function wasn't introduced until v.x.y.

Is there a standard way to see a particular function's earliest appearance in its library? In my case, I'm looking to see when the `df.quantile()` method first appeared in pandas. Perhaps it was there from the earliest version. Idk. I don't see this info in the documentation. Perhaps I'm just missing it? Or does it not exist anywhere that's easily searchable?

Comment: You could check out the source on github, and do something like git blame.